# Godot: Compiled source project doesn't open in windows 10

Tags: visual-c++, scons, godot

I was able to successfully compile the Godot engine for windows 10. I used the following command and got no errors on completion.

> scons -j6 p=windows tools=yes

However when I run the created `godot.windows.tools.64`. The application shows the prompt and loses immediately. 
I decided to run it in Visual Studio. The same thing happened but I got this in the command line:

```
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Godot Source\godot\bin\godot.windows.tools.32.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\umpdc.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput8.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avrt.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\InputHost.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DXCore.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. 
'godot.windows.tools.32.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
The thread 0x2fdc has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The thread 0x2f7c has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The thread 0x168 has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The thread 0x27f4 has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The thread 0x2e88 has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The thread 0xc74 has exited with code 255 (0xff).
The program '[4128] godot.windows.tools.32.exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff).
```

As a note, I am running Windows 10 on a intel i5 with HD graphics GPU, 
Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0),
VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16,
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.24.28127,
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK

Comment: Where did you place the compiled binary? If you place it at the root of a project folder, it will run the project immediately instead of bringing up the project manager or editor. You can override this behavior by passing the `--project-manager` or `--editor` command-line arguments.

Comment: I think I solved this issue. I switched from the `master` branch to `3.2`

Comment: I solved this issue. I switched from the `master` branch to `3.2`

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from a comment)*.

I solved this issue. I switched from the master branch to 3.2.